# PHP API - Friends by date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get the friends list by the date they added?

Or How long two users are friends. I have seen some questions like this. But they are old. I don't know whether facebook have added any options for this.

I want to use graph api - php

Comment: Have you tried something atleast?

Comment: No. I didn't try anything apart from api. I don't know whether anything newly added in graph api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't provide any way to retrieve such information.